# In TinyMCE if I'm serving the code myself instead of via the cloud does registering the domain matter?

Tags: tinymce

Right now I'm using TinyMCE via the cloud and have this in my header (I've modified the long code-like string):

```
https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/9vmocp7n8n2v4dp83uvmpcicm6zt74px/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js
```

I assume that long string is like some sort of api key where I've registered my domains.

If I download the package and serve tinymce.min.js locally would there still be a long string like that, and would the domains matter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script tag with a URL that looks like:

```
https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/YOUR_API_KEY_HERE/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js
```

...will load TinyMCE from Tiny's Cloud Platform. Your account is tied to your API key. When make a call to load TinyMCE from that URL with your API key, the Cloud Platform will confirm the domain you are attempting to load Tiny from by comparing it to the list of domains you can register at:

https://apps.tiny.cloud/my-account/

Your API key is also used to manage any Cloud-based commercial plugins you may have purchased.

If you download the open source version of TinyMCE here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/

...then you will install and run TinyMCE completely on your own server. Your application would not make any calls to Tiny's Cloud platform, so there are no domains to register or manage. Self-hosted TinyMCE in this manner is completely separate from TinyMCE Cloud.

Comment: If I'm interested in support would I need to run the cloud version?

Comment: Tiny's Support platform is available with any paid plan, Cloud or Self-hosted. Opening a Cloud trial at tiny.cloud includes access to Support as part of its 30-day trial.